# Restrict EditText to accept only Urls in Android

Tags: android

I am writing an application in which I need to restrict EditText to accept URLs only. How can this be done in Android?

Answer (score 10):

Open the Properties of your EditBox. Property InputType offers you a list of checkboxes, and one of them is `textUri`.

Comment: Yes, because it is tricky decision. What if you are not writing your URI starting from beggining. This approach works well for numbers and date, because it is easier to limit your input via keyboard. I am afraid that you will need to do sanity check anyway. Use android.net.Uri for that.

Comment: As I understand it the `inputType` on a `EditText` is only sort of a guideline provided to the keyboard for how it's supposed to behave. Different keyboards may behave differently. There by it won't restrict you from typing non-url characters, unless the current keyboard layout is the restrictor.

Comment: Please take into account that judging what is valid URI and what is not may be somewhat tricky task. So, for this specific case, EditText is not so restrictive. On the other hand, if you specify that only dialable digits are allowed (PhoneNumber) you will get exactly the behaviour you have asked for.

Answer (score 1):

It is also working with EditTextPreference although is not shown as property.